# Flex NumericStepper with leading 0 on numbers below 10?

Tags: apache-flex, numericstepper

- Is there a way to make NumericStepper shows leading 0 to numbers which is below 10 ?

*( like 01, 02, 03 ... 09, 10, 11 )*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using the Spark NumericStepper, you should just add a function for the [valueFormatFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/NumericStepper.html#valueFormatFunction) property.

Comment: never even thinked that there is ready to be used property like this. Thank you very much . :)

Comment: Nice one :D I remember that with halo components it was really a pain in the ass.

Comment: This doesn't always work if you edit manually the value in the numeric stepper's text input. How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: @MadBlack How are you updating this value 'manually'?  It's been a while since I've looked through the code, but I was fairly sure that the value would automatically 'update' using the format function after the commitProperties/updateDisplayList function gets called, which should be done automatically when setting a new value.  It could be that you're doing something that's circumventing that.

Comment: I just have done that: I've put two numeric step controls in a widget on of them had the format function declared to add a leading zero. I've manually put a single digit in the numeric step control with the format function then I've switched on the other control and then come back again. At this point adding manually a single digit in the numeric stepper did not trigger the format function and the digit sadly remain single. I seems to me that the format fucntion is  tied only to the interaction with the little arrows in the control.

Comment: @MadBlack I'm asking for code, man.  I still don't know how you're updating the values.

Comment: Here you are man.  `private function addLeadingZeroToMinutes( value: Number ): String {  
    return( value < 10 ? "0" + value : value.toString() );  
   } // eof`

Comment: That's only the formatter, I'm asking for how you're updating the numeric stepper.  Also, you should really look at some of the [formatters that come with flex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf648c2-7fff.html) like the DateTimeFormatter which might do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is looking for a Halo only version:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    import mx.controls.NumericStepper;
    import mx.core.mx_internal;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    use namespace mx_internal;
    /**
     * Added support to format time values.
     */ 
    public class TimePickerNumericStepper extends NumericStepper
    {
        public function TimePickerNumericStepper()
        {
        }

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        override protected function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();
            onValueCommit(null)
            inputField.addEventListener(FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT,onValueCommit);
        }

        protected function onValueCommit(event:Event):void
        {
            if(value<10 && inputField.text.length==1){
                inputField.text = "0" + inputField.text;
            }   
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are in Flex 3 you can't access directly to the inputField, but easy you can solve it by using mx_internal

```
<mx:NumericStepper id="stpprHours" minimum="1" maximum="24" stepSize="1" creationComplete="formatStepper(stpprHours)" change="stpprHours_changeHandler(event)" value="1"/>

<mx:NumericStepper id="stpprMinutes" minimum="0" maximum="59" stepSize="1" creationComplete="formatStepper(stpprMinutes)" change="stpprMinutes_changeHandler(event)" value="0"/>
```

and

```
<mx:Script>
 <CDATA[[
        protected function stpprHours_changeHandler(event:NumericStepperEvent):void {
            formatStepper(stpprHours);              
        }

        protected function stpprMinutes_changeHandler(event:NumericStepperEvent):void {
            formatStepper(stpprMinute);                             
        }

        protected function formatStepper(stepper : NumericStepper) : void {
            if(stepper.value<10) stepper.mx_internal::inputField.text = "0" + stepper.value;

    }
 ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yury Euceda version is working great. I would like to followup as the following to decouple the control from the event handler.

```
private function init( event:FlexEvent ):void{
        scheduleHour.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onStepperChange);
        scheduleMinute.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onStepperChange);
        scheduleHour.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
        scheduleMinute.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
}
```

and

```
        public function onStepperChange (ev:Event) : void {
            var stepper:NumericStepper  = ev.currentTarget as NumericStepper;
            var num:String = stepper.value > 10 ? "" + stepper.value : "0" + stepper.value;
            stepper.mx_internal::inputField.text = num;
        }
```